# Unsupported Protocol in MiKTeX package manager

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I have had a MiKTeX installation on this computer for several years and it has worked mostly smoothly. However, since today, when trying to install new packages using the package manager I get the following error:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Unsupported protocol
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp
Line: 402
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Business Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
Invokers: non-existing/explorer
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\JonasAdler\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\JonasAdler\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: E:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\JonasAdler\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\JonasAdler\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\JonasAdler\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: E:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

I can still run MiKTeX as usual, i.e. build documents etc, but any attempt to install new packages gives this error message.

In addition, If i try to change my remote package repository, I get this very cryptic list of repositories:

[image: Package manager screenshot]

I have, to the best of my knowledge, not changed anything with the MikTeX installation myself since the last time I successfully used MiKTeX.

Edit: I have now encountered this problem on 3 of my windows machines, including 2 with windows 7 and one with windows 10. They all get the exact same error message and were all working just a few days ago.

Comment: Works fine for me on windows 10. Did you check for updates (as admin and as user)?

Comment: I have similar problems with MiKTeX and see the same cryptic repository list in the package manager. I have this issue on two different computers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As indicated in the post, I have tried checking for updates but cannot find any repository when manually checking. If i try to use "Use the nearest package repository" I get the same message as above, e.g. "Sorry something went wrong, unsupported protocol"

Comment: Do you have a multiuser installation? Did you try the admin version of the tool? And when was the last time that you did an update (admin)?

Comment: It is a multiuser installation and I have tried with the admin tool (and without). The last time was perhaps a few months ago.

Comment: Just adding a comment that I tried MiKTeX on another computer just now and I'm getting the exact same error so it does not seem like this is a local error.

Comment: I have experienced similar problems with MiKTeX in the past several times, and I have been using MikTeX for many years now. The problems I had may not be exactly same as this one, but they are  always fixed ina matter of days if not hours. If it s a systemwide problem, I am guessing that it will be solved soon as there are many users reporting an issue. You may also report one.   So my recommendation is to wait a bit if you do not need it urgently. (BTW, I have jsut tried mine, it works just as fine. May be it is fixed now?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it was a bug on the server side and the maintainer (Christian Schenk) has fixed it. Should work now (it does on my machine without the need to reinstall anything)
https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2609/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I also had this cryptic entry in the package manager repository list. I solved this by completely removing MiKTeX and reinstalling it (non multi-user). Now I get a full list of repositories.